# `Future.failed` inside of `transformWith[Array[Byte]]` gives a compiler error

Tags: scala, akka, future, akka-http, jackson-databind

I'm attempting to analyze an `HttpResponse` from Akka. The ideal behavior is that if the response comes back successfully, pass the `Array[Byte]` representation of the `HttpEntity` along for processing. However, if the status comes back as a failure, pass a `Future.failed` with an exception along, containing the status code and a JSON tree representation of the `HttpEntity` along. The reason to pass along a JSON tree is that there are different servers being hit by this abstract request method, and they format their responses differently, so I want to handle the parsing of the response in those other classes.

I've attempted a variety of manipulations of this workflow. Throwing the exception outright instead of returning a `Future.failed` returns a `None` value in place of the JSON tree in the exception. Other methods produce similar results. When I `println(MAPPER.readTree(byteArray))` it prints out the response as I expect, but then proceeds to return `None` in the `response` field of the `BadRequestException`.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers.Authorization
import akka.stream.Materializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, JsonNode, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val MAPPER = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
  MAPPER.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  MAPPER.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

def performQueryRaw(method: HttpMethod, uri: Uri, entity: Option[RequestEntity] = None, authorization: Option[Authorization] = None): Future[Array[Byte]] = {

  val request: HttpRequest = HttpRequest(
    method = method,
    uri = uri,
    entity = entity.getOrElse(HttpEntity.Empty),
    headers = authorization.toList)

  http.singleRequest(request).transformWith[Array[Byte]] {
    case Success(response: HttpResponse) =>
      convertEntityToBytes(response.entity).map { byteArray =>
        if (response.status.isFailure()) Future.failed(BadRequestException(response.status, MAPPER.readTree(byteArray)))
        else byteArray
      }
      case Failure(throwable) => Future.failed(RequestFailedException(throwable.getMessage + " -- " + uri.toString, throwable))
    }
  }

def convertEntityToBytes(entity: HttpEntity): Future[Array[Byte]] = {
  entity.dataBytes.runFold[Seq[Array[Byte]]] (Nil) {
    case (acc, next) => acc :+ next.toArray
  }.map(_.flatten.toArray)
}

case class BadRequestException(status: StatusCode, response: JsonNode = None.orNull, t: Throwable = None.orNull) extends Exception(t)

case class RequestFailedException(message: String, t: Throwable = None.orNull) extends Exception(message, t)
```

I'm expecting a `BadRequestException` out with a non-none value for JsonNode. Instead, I'm getting a compiler error on the `Future.failed` that reads:

`Expression of type Future[Nothing] doesn't conform to expected type Array[Byte]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flatMap` instead of `map` when you run next step after `convertEntityToBytes`:

```
def performQueryRaw(
    method: HttpMethod,
    uri: Uri,
    entity: Option[RequestEntity] = None,
    authorization: Option[Authorization] = None
  ): Future[Array[Byte]] = {

    val request: HttpRequest = HttpRequest(
      method = method,
      uri = uri,
      entity = entity.getOrElse(HttpEntity.Empty),
      headers = authorization.toList
    )

    Http().singleRequest(request).transformWith[Array[Byte]] {
      case Success(response: HttpResponse) =>
        convertEntityToBytes(response.entity).flatMap { byteArray =>
          if (response.status.isFailure()) Future.failed(new Exception("change this exception to one you had"))
          else Future.successful(byteArray)
        }
      case Failure(throwable) => Future.failed(new Exception("also here"))
    }
  }
```

Since you wann fail you `Future` computation, you need to return new `Future`. In case of failure, you have been already doing `Future.failed`. Missing piece was also to wrap a byteArray to `Future.successful`. Of course this one of the way to solve type compilation error in this code.

Comment: I'm marking this as solving my issue, because it solves the compiler error. Didn't solve the issue of `MAPPER.readTree(byteArray)` being null in the exception, but I managed to solve that one on my own. I converted the `response` to an `Option[JsonNode]` defaulting to `None`. Thanks!